# C++ query related to KVM server

Tags: discussion

Can I ask C++ question which are related to KVM & LVM server on server fault or I need to ask them only on "stack overflow" or "programmers" ? I am asking this because I need much of hardware info than C++ but the query is truly C++ based.

Also I need to know Can I ask same question one more than one site of stack exchange? please  suggest.

Comment: I think I have figured it out in FAQ's

I think I might just need to figure out both the parts separately and then give my detail research with both the tags and then I should ask the query if required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I ask same question one more than one site of stack exchange?

You should not.  You should look at the FAQ serverfault.com/faq or stackoverflow.com/faq.  If your question does not clearly belong on the site, then don't ask it ask it on that site..  If you do think it belongs then ask it on the site you think **fits best**.  If we disagree we will move it.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about developing KVM-related C++ software should be on Stack Overflow.
Questions about interactions with KVM in an administrative-viewpoint and particularly error therein go on Server Fault.

For the most part, your questions should go on SO.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I think I have figured it out in FAQ's

I think I might just need to figure out both the parts separately and then give my detail research with both the tags and then I should ask the query if required.

Answer (score 2):

If a programming language tag is appropriate to the question it is very unlikely that the question is appropriate for Server Fault. Tags such as `c++`, `c#`, etc. shouldn't even exist on SF because they belong only on programming questions.

Comment: I admit the the questions with tag of a programming language should be on programming questions but my query is KVM Server based on virtualization but since I am implementing it in C++ and may include some of the code snippets discussion also thats why I was concerned about posting here. any way I'll do it on programming question and filter the KVm discussion on server fault.

Comment: If the code snippets are relevant then it's a programming question it belongs on SO. If you ask about getting information from a device but frame it without it being a programming question then it may well suitable for SF. Many of us are indeed devs as well as sysadmins but we need to keep the topics separate. I do understand it's not always easy to separate the different facets of writing applications but it must be done.

Comment: thanks for the explanation john. I'll keep thin in mind for my future references.